# GCC have: command not found [: too many argument

Tags: gcc, debian

This is my first post, so if I do it something wrong - sorry ;)

I have problem with Debian, which don't have access to internet and will not.

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-5-686 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze6) (jmm@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:33:32 UTC 2014
```

I want to monitore it by SNMP, but when I try install it I have a issue.

```
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# sudo ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Below config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by Net-SNMP configure 5.9.1, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = debian
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 2.6.32-5-686
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:33:32 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/X11R6/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:3402: checking for gcc
configure:3418: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3429: result: gcc
configure:3658: checking for C compiler version
configure:3667: gcc --version >&5
/usr/bin/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/usr/bin/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
configure:3678: $? = 2
configure:3667: gcc -v >&5
/usr/bin/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/usr/bin/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
configure:3678: $? = 2
configure:3667: gcc -V >&5
/usr/bin/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/usr/bin/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
configure:3678: $? = 2
configure:3667: gcc -qversion >&5
/usr/bin/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/usr/bin/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
configure:3678: $? = 2
configure:3698: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3720: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/usr/bin/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
configure:3724: $? = 2
configure:3762: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Net-SNMP"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "net-snmp"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "5.9.1"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Net-SNMP 5.9.1"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define NETSNMP_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3767: error: in `/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1':
configure:3769: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBNL3_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBNL3_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBNL3_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBNL3_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AGENTLIBS=''
AGENT_INCLUDES=''
ALLOCA=''
AR=''
AS=''
AUTOCONF=''
AUTOHEADER=''
AWK=''
CC='gcc'
CCPATH=''
CFLAGS=''
CONFIGURE_OPTIONS='""'
COPY_PERSISTENT_FILES=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DEVFLAGS=''
DLLIBS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DPKG_QUERY_PATH=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EMBEDPERLINSTALL=''
EMBEDPERLUNINSTALL=''
ENV_SEPARATOR=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTERNAL_MIBGROUP_INCLUDES=''
EXTRACPPFLAGS=''
FEATUREHEADERS=''
FEATURETARGS=''
FEATURE_ADD_FLAGS=''
FEATURE_REMOVE_FLAGS=''
FGREP=''
FILE=''
FIND=''
FTMAINSUBS=''
GNU_vpath=''
GREP=''
HAVE_LIBCURSES=''
HELPER_INCLUDES=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PREFIX=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LAGENTLIBS=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LD_NO_UNDEFINED=''
LIBCURSES=''
LIBNL3_CFLAGS=''
LIBNL3_LIBS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOLFLAGS=''
LIBTOOL_DEPS=''
LINKCC=''
LIPO=''
LMIBLIBS=''
LNETSNMPLIBS=''
LN_S=''
LPSTAT_PATH=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH=''
MAINSUBS=''
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MIBGROUP_INCLUDES=''
MYSQLCONFIG=''
MYSQL_INCLUDES=''
MYSQL_LIBS=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_PCAP_PROG_FALSE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_PCAP_PROG_TRUE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_SET_PROG_FALSE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_SET_PROG_TRUE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_SSH_PROG_FALSE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_SSH_PROG_TRUE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_TLS_PROG_FALSE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_TLS_PROG_TRUE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_USM_PROG_FALSE=''
NETSNMP_BUILD_USM_PROG_TRUE=''
NETSNMP_DEFAULT_MIBDIRS=''
NETSNMP_DEFAULT_MIBS=''
NETSNMP_HAVE_AGENTX_LIBS_FALSE=''
NETSNMP_HAVE_AGENTX_LIBS_TRUE=''
NM=''
NMEDIT=''
NON_GNU_VPATH=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTHERAGENTLIBLFTS=''
OTHERAGENTLIBLOBJS=''
OTHERAGENTLIBOBJS=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net'
PACKAGE_NAME='Net-SNMP'
PACKAGE_STRING='Net-SNMP 5.9.1'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='net-snmp'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='5.9.1'
PARTIALTARGETFLAGS=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERLARGS=''
PERLFEATURES=''
PERLINSTALLTARGS=''
PERLLDOPTS_FOR_APPS=''
PERLLDOPTS_FOR_LIBS=''
PERLPROG=''
PERLTARGS=''
PERLUNINSTALLTARGS=''
PERL_SYSTEM_INVOKES_POSIX_SHELL=''
PERSISTENT_DIRECTORY=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PSCMD=''
PSPROG=''
PYTHONARGS=''
PYTHONCLEANTARGS=''
PYTHONFEATURES=''
PYTHONINSTALLTARGS=''
PYTHONPROG=''
PYTHONTARGS=''
PYTHONUNINSTALLTARGS=''
RANLIB=''
RC=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SNMPCONFPATH=''
SNMPD=''
SNMPLIBPATH=''
SNMPLIB_INCLUDES=''
SNMPSHAREPATH=''
STRIP=''
TOP_INCLUDES=''
TRAPLIBS=''
UCDPERSISTENT_DIRECTORY=''
UNAMEPROG=''
USETRAPLIBS=''
VAL_LIBS=''
VERSION=''
WHOAMI=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
ac_cv_NETSNMP_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_FILE=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
crypto_files_c=''
crypto_files_lo=''
crypto_files_o=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
default_mibs_install=''
dllcleans=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
installucdheaders=''
installucdlibs=''
krb5_config=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
other_agentobjs=''
other_ftagentobjs=''
other_ftobjs_list=''
other_lagentobjs=''
other_lobjs_list=''
other_objs_list=''
other_src_list=''
other_trapd_objects=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
security_ftobj_list=''
security_hdr_list=''
security_lobj_list=''
security_obj_list=''
security_src_list=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target=''
target_alias=''
target_cpu=''
target_os=''
target_vendor=''
transport_ftobj_list=''
transport_hdr_list=''
transport_lobj_list=''
transport_obj_list=''
transport_src_list=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

MODULE_LIST=''
agent_module_list_c=''
agent_module_list_deps=''
agent_module_list_ft=''
agent_module_list_lo=''
agent_module_list_o=''
agentgroup_list_ft=''
agentgroup_list_lo=''
agentgroup_list_o=''
mib_module_list_c=''
mib_module_list_deps=''
mib_module_list_ft=''
mib_module_list_lo=''
mib_module_list_o=''
mibgroup_list_ft=''
mibgroup_list_lo=''
mibgroup_list_o=''
module_list_c=''
module_list_deps=''
module_list_ft=''
module_list_lo=''
module_list_o=''
module_rules=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "Net-SNMP"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "net-snmp"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "5.9.1"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "Net-SNMP 5.9.1"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define NETSNMP_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS ""

configure: exit 77
```

I tried to find solution about gcc, but only I found:

```
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# ls /usr/bin | grep gcc
gcc
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# /usr/bin/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/usr/bin/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# /etc/bash_completion.d/gcc
/etc/bash_completion.d/gcc: line 11: have: command not found
/etc/bash_completion.d/gcc: line 50: [: too many arguments
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# ls -l /etc/bash_completion.d/gcc
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1604 Nov 16  2010 /etc/bash_completion.d/gcc
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# cat /etc/environment
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Below what is include gcc file:

```
root@debian:/home/rkrainski/net-snmp-5.9.1# cat /etc/bash_completion.d/gcc
# gcc(1) completion
#
# The only unusual feature is that we don't parse "gcc --help -v" output
# directly, because that would include the options of all the other backend
# tools (linker, assembler, preprocessor, etc) without any indication that
# you cannot feed such options to the gcc driver directly.  (For example, the
# linker takes a -z option, but you must type -Wl,-z for gcc.)  Instead, we
# ask the driver ("g++") for the name of the compiler ("cc1"), and parse the
# --help output of the compiler.

have gcc &&
_gcc()
{
    local cur cc backend

    COMPREPLY=()
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur

    _expand || return 0

    case $1 in
        gcj)
            backend=jc1
            ;;
        gpc)
            backend=gpc1
            ;;
        *77)
            backend=f771
            ;;
        *)
            backend=cc1 # (near-)universal backend
            ;;
    esac

    if [[ "$cur" == -* ]]; then
        cc=$( $1 -print-prog-name=$backend )
        # sink stderr:
        # for C/C++/ObjectiveC it's useless
        # for FORTRAN/Java it's an error
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( $cc --help 2>/dev/null | \
           tr '\t' ' ' | \
           sed -e '/^  *-/!d' -e 's/ *-\([^ ]*\).*/-\1/' | \
           sort -u )" -- "$cur" ) )
    else
        _filedir
    fi
} &&
complete -o filenames -F _gcc gcc g++ c++ g77 gcj gpc
[ $USERLAND = GNU -o $UNAME = Cygwin ] && \
[ -n "${have:-}" ] && complete -o filenames -F _gcc cc

# Local variables:
# mode: shell-script
# sh-basic-offset: 4
# sh-indent-comment: t
# indent-tabs-mode: nil
# End:
# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```

cat /etc/bash.bashrc

```
root@debian:/home/rkrainski# cat /etc/bash.bashrc
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
        function command_not_found_handle {
                # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/bin/python /usr/share/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
                else
                   return 127
                fi
        }
fi
```

cat ~/.bashrc

```
root@debian:/home/rkrainski# cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
```

mount | grep noexec

```
root@debian:/home/rkrainski# mount | grep noexec
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
```

I tried to instal gcc offline but still the same error: `checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`

Do You have any ideas? Don't forgot that PC don't have internet access.

Thank You in advance

Comment: I do not know, but it is wrong to run configure (and in general to compile) using superuser (and so sudo). `sudo` is just for installing (and often unnecessary, it you are the only user of the program, or if you are building a package). -- Maybe that is really the problem (sudo messing up with interactive shell), or your .bashrc may have some problem. bash completition should not be used on non-interactive shells

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi without sudo the same situation

Comment: So check why bash_completion is used on a non-interactive shell. Check what you changed on various bashrc and profile

Comment: Just move that file out of /etc/bash.completion.d while you're building your application. The issue regarding line 50 is probably related to `$USERLAND` and `$UNAME` not being surrounded by quotes. The one line 11 shows that you don't have a command nor an alias for `have`. Basically, that file doesn't do anything, except throwing those two errors.

Comment: For `C compiler cannot create executables`, look at `configure`, line 3769, what is it doing? Can you run that command yourself, trying to figure out what's wrong? Are we sure GCC is installed? Maybe the working directory is mounted with a `noexec` option?

Comment: @SYN You are right when I add quotes error disapear. In my question I added data about bashrc and noexec. I hope GCC is installed but on this host I see problem on each step ;)

Comment: This looks like you have replaced `/usr/bin/gcc` with a broken wrapper of some sort. Where does it come from and what does it contain? What do you get from `dpkg -S /usr/bin/gcc`? What about `file /usr/bin/gcc`? If it's a text file, what about `head /usr/bin/gcc`?

Comment: Having said that, I don't think this is reproducible (and the digression into Bash completions is probably a complete red herring). Out of the box, if you `apt-get install -y build-essential` you get a chain of symlinks to the binary, in my case `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-8` (1100664 bytes, Apr 6 2019).

Comment: The year 2011 Debian Squeeze : You can get gcc, g++, libc6-dev etc. from the DVD set https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/6.0.10/i386/iso-dvd/ ... i.e. gcc alone doesn't work. Hence `build-essential`